# Group stored procedures in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, namespaces

We are writing tons of oracle stored procedures to handle our business logic. We would like to do a physical grouping for better maintenance and understanding.

I can see package is helpful for encapsulation and logical grouping... Is there anyway we can create namespace physically to group certain procedures based on business logic.

Please advice us on this...

Comment: I think you might have better luck asking this question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you David!!!

Comment: As per Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch14.htm *all parts of database procedures are stored in the data dictionary (which is in the SYSTEM tablespace)*. Not sure if this property can be changed. You may create an exclusive **schema** for owning all the procedures/functions as per business logic and grant  execute permissions to appropriate users on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [`PACKAGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/packages.htm):

```
CREATE PACKAGE package_name AS
  PROCEDURE procedure_name1;

  PROCEDURE procedure_name2( arg1 NUMBER );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_name AS
  PROCEDURE procedure_name1
  IS
  BEGIN NULL; END;

  PROCEDURE procedure_name2( arg1 NUMBER )
  IS
  BEGIN NULL; END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks MTO... But writing 50 to 60 procedures inside package body is gonna be complex for maintenance.. Please share your thoughts on this

Comment: Can you explain your concerns about increased maintenance complexity? I find 50-60 procedures much easier to manage inside packages than floating around disorganized. All IDEs let you easily jump around to procedure definitions within the package.

Comment: If 50 or 60 is too much, then spit the packages out to smaller units. But the PACKAGE solution is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith and kfinity